# Mobile Website Wont Scroll Although Scrollbar is appearing

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile, web, scroll

I am just building a new website which is using a responsive wordpress theme.

The site URL is - www.render-box.co.uk/new/

The site looks fine to me when it scales down to mobile size, yet when viewing on a mobile I can't scroll down. The scrollbar is appearing at the side of the page.

It seems as if something is blocking the page from scrolling, and I'm not quite sure what?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. If you inspect the code, there's a script that puts: "overflow:hidden" in the HTML Tag. (I guess it's because the custom scroll bar, actually it's the niceScroll plugin doing that and it's not for mobile).... So, you can make a script to override the nicescroll.

I made this for you, this will check the UserAgent to detect if the user is on a mobile device and then, override the css rule of the html tag. Hope this works for you.

```
    $(function(){

        var movil=false;

        if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || 
            navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) ||
            navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || 
            navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)|| 
            navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || 
            navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)){

            var movil=true;

        }

        else{
            var movil=false
        }


        if(movil==true){

            // SET OVERFLOW TO AUTO, SO THE SCROLL IT'S ALLOWED

            $("html").css("overflow", "auto");

            //HIDE THE NICESCROLL FOR MOBILE DEVICES 

            $("#ascrail2000").css("display", "none");


        }

        else{}
    });
```

Don't forget to put this on a  tag on the end of the html, when the DOM is ready, so it will overwrite the css.